# Get current index in fragment of ViewPager

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-viewpager

Using a sliding ViewPager I want to create a list of articles. During the move, I want to dynamically change the title in the action bar. Titles are stored in the list of strings, and the title of each list is the position of the current fragment. So, for example, given this list:

```
List<String> leftItems = new List<String> ();
leftItems.Add ("First title");
leftItems.Add ("Second title");
leftItems.Add ("Third title");
```

I would like to while watching the fragment 2 (index 1) is displayed title

> Second title

Title to the action bar in the fragment I change this code:

```
((ActionBarActivity)Activity).SupportActionBar.Title = this.leftItems[this.position];
```

The variable 'position', which comes with the adapter in the method GetItem ():

```
public override Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment GetItem(int position) {
            return new ArticlesFragment (this.articles [this.leftItems [position]], 
                this.leftItems, this.position);
        }

public ArticlesFragment(List<Article> articles, List<String> leftItems, int position) : base() {
            this.articles = articles;
            this.leftItems = leftItems;
            this.position = position;
        }
```

With what I have a problem? Well, the title of the action bar is always one index greater than it should. So for fragment 1 (index 0), the title is

> Second title

and not as I want

> First title

But, in the last fragment, the title does not change, only stays with the previous fragment.

Does someone can help me?

@edit

I add the entire contents of the adapter and a fragment:

ArticlesFragmentAdapter.cs

```
public class ArticlesFragmentAdapter : FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    Dictionary<String, List<Article>> articles;
    List<String> leftItems;

    public ArticlesFragmentAdapter(Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager fm, 
        Dictionary<String, List<Article>> articles,
        List<String> leftItems) : base(fm) {
        this.articles = articles;
        this.leftItems = leftItems;
    }

    public override int Count {
        get { return this.leftItems.Count; }
    }

    public override Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment GetItem(int position) {
        return new ArticlesFragment (this.articles [this.leftItems [position]], 
            this.leftItems, position);
    }
}
```

ArticlesFragment.cs

```
public class ArticlesFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment {
    List<Article> articles;
    List<String> leftItems;
    ListView articlesListView;
    int position;
    ArticlesAdapter articlesAdapter;

    public ArticlesFragment(List<Article> articles, List<String> leftItems, int position) : base() {
        this.articles = articles;
        this.leftItems = leftItems;
        this.position = position;
    }

    public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, 
        ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var view = inflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.Articles, container, false);

        this.articlesListView = view.FindViewById<ListView> (Resource.Id.articlesListView);
        ((ActionBarActivity)Activity).SupportActionBar.Title = this.leftItems[this.position - 1];

        this.articlesAdapter = new ArticlesAdapter ((ActionBarActivity)this.Activity, this.articles);

        this.articlesListView.Adapter = this.articlesAdapter;

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use the http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html#onPageSelected(int) to update the title in the activity when the page changes

Comment: You mean something like this? ((ActionBarActivity)Activity).SupportActionBar.Title = this.leftItems[this.position - 1]; If so, then when you try to view the first fragment I get an exception: IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: then i suspect something in the code you have not posted is incorrect. The indexes do not change so you are likely using the wrong ones somewhere. i.e index 0 is always "First Title" It is impossible for index 0 to return "Second Title" using the code you have posted

Comment: I added the code of both classes. Maybe now you'll be able to help me?

Comment: why are you passing the complete leftitems array and a position into each fragment. you only want the title so why not just store the relevant title in the fragment. it makes no sense to store all of the titles in every fragment. just store the one you actually need.

Comment: you could also use the http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html#onPageSelected(int) to update the title in the activity when the page changes.

Comment: In addition, doing what you are doing will cause crashes later. you need to store fragment data using setArguments(). When your fragments are destroyed and recreated, they will lose all of the values you have passed into them as variables. You should not set fragment data using constructors.

Comment: Thanks! I used OnPageChangeListener and now it's working properly. Also thanks for the advice storing data in the fragment.